# PCB track antenna or SMD chip antenna for BLE 5?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, data-transfer, design-guidelines

I am referring the options to choose antenna for data transfer over Bluetooth 5. Any guidelines to choose between these two- SMD Chip antenna or PCB track antenna.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.digikey.jp/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/Pulse_553/PDF/pulse_ceramic-chip-antennas-vs-pcb-trace-antennas.pdf

Comment: Chip antennas can be small, but they have notoriously low gain. PCB track antennas (PIFA and similar) can be large, but are essentially "free" if you have the space available.  Software like Remcom's XFDTD ($$$$) can make designing PCB antennas relatively easy.  Both sorts of antennas are sensitive to the enclosure and surrounding materials. "cookbook" designs are usually not very good in real world situations except on a bare PCB in air.